# How to post access token parameter to the Gmail api

Tags: http, gmail-api

I am using gmail api to modify some label for a certain message below

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/id/modify
```

but the google developer in https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify
did not state the need to pass in the access token, how do I pass the access token to the api to modify the label for the messsage?

Rgds

Vincent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are parameters sent in an HTTP POST request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request)

Answer (score 2):

You could either put it in a query parameter:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/id/modify?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

Or in the Authorization header:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/id/modify
Authorization: Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

Comment: Actually my problem is the documentation in https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify do not have clear indication on how to call this api, not sure if it using access token or api key>

Comment: @pjsiong Ah, I see. The key can be used to try your own mail if I'm not mistaking. I have never tried that. You will have to use the `access token` of your real users later though. You can authorize with the Gmail API scopes at the [Oauth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) and use that for testing.

Comment: Hi, I tried in the playground and it return with below error                                           POST /gmail/v1/users/sndata%40abc.com/messages/152e915a67e36fdc/modify?access_token=ya29.iwKoFjRabp8JDVWZUaQPvTLzq-eQ7mERN91t4PEAz33432345IqHbkbQ0KmJzfkAu3nJQxA&access_token=ya29.iwLGVygU5zY3JPGAG7Yxqge-aYAb80yYZ432342343CTcHYMy40LAS_F2_Azl_Wwxb_q HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 34
Content-type: application/json
{ "removeLabelIds": [  "UNREAD" ]}

Comment: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-length: 249
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Expires: Wed, 17 Feb 2016 07:52:45 GMT
Vary: Origin,X-Origin
Server: GSE
Cache-control: private, max-age=0
Date: Wed, 17 Feb 2016 07:52:45 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Www-authenticate: Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/", error=invalid_token

Comment: {
  "error": {
    "code": 401, 
    "message": "Invalid Credentials", 
    "errors": [
      {
        "locationType": "header", 
        "domain": "global", 
        "message": "Invalid Credentials", 
        "reason": "authError", 
        "location": "Authorization"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: @pjsiong Just give the `access_token` once.